# Perl Regural Expression | How to use negative lookahead(?!) inside a non capturing group (?:)

Tags: regex, perl, authentication, qregularexpression

I want to use a negative look-ahead inside a non capturing group in Perl Regex. So far i have create an expression that not allows 3 "pairs of characters" into a string

```
CASE 1: ^(?!(?:\w*(.)\1){3}).+$

For example the string: Mytte!3sttStrring  | Not pass - 3 pairs | "tt","tt","rr"
```

If you see there is a negative look-ahead before the group, i want to add this expression into a group. To understand this i will present you an other example that disallows only one pair or chars.

```
CASE 2 : no match if there is a pair in string:   (?=^(?:(.)(?!\1))*$)
```

If you test these 2 expressions in https://regex101.com/ you will see that for the string "MySampleString" on the **CASE 2** I have 2 Match Information. (Full Match and Group 1 Match).
Now if you run the first pattern (**CASE 1**) you will see only the Full Match at Match Information.

In my try add grouping match option in the CASE 1 putting brackets around:

```
CASE 1 my try:   (^(?!(?:\w*(.)\1){3}).+$)
```

but now the expression inside doesn't work :/

I want to find a way that ^(?!(?:\w*(.)\1){3}).+$ will work (with Full Match and Group1 Match). I have to add this option to a very long regular expression that I'm working on and it cant work as a full match group. 
To make it cleaner i will show you an example that the String must not have a "pair of chars" and at the same time not to include 4 repetitions of any letter.

```
        (?=^(?:(.)(?!\1))*$)(?=^(?:(.)(?!(?:.*?\1){4}))*$)
```

These 2 expressions   (?=^(?:(.)(?!\1))*$) and (?=^(?:(.)(?!(?:.*?\1){4}))*$) combined because both have a grouping match.

Comment: Could you please explain your real problem? What is the regex?  I suspect you just want to add  a restriction to its beginning, that the string cannot contain 3 or more repeated consecutive chars. You need to make sure the capturing group and the backreferences correspond: `^(?!(?:\w*(.)\1){3}).....`. If you want to check for any chars, replace `\w*` with `.*`. The regex will be very inefficient.

Comment: REGEX: Regular Expression | my real problem is that like i can combine these two different regular Expressions  (?=^(?:(.)(?!\1))$) and (?=^(?:(.)(?!(?:.?\1){4}))*$) into one like i show you at the end of the post. I want to make the combination  of ^(?!(?:\w*(.)\1){3}).+$ and  (?=^(?:(.)(?!(?:.?\1){4}))*$)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Stribiżew Its very clear... Try to run (?=^(?:(.)(?!\1))*$)(?=^(?:(.)(?!(?:.*?\1){4}))*$) that exclude string with (one pair) and not (4 repetitions of a same character ). This one runs... Now try to run (?=^(?!(?:\w*(.)\1){3}).+$)(?=^(?:(.)(?!(?:.*?\1){4}))*$)  that i want to exclude string with (thee pairs)and not (4 repetitions of a same character ). This one NOT runs

Comment: Something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/wtmBQE/1)? `^(?=(?:.*(.)\1){3})(?!(?:.*(.)\2){4})`? You have two *capturing* groups now and the backreference in one is `\1` and in the other it must be `\2`.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew In this link it work if there are 3 pairs of chars (i need no to work if there are no 3 pairs inside my String), also the second expression not worked.                             For example i want the strings    "M@yttesst11"  to fail because there are 3 pairs inside,  also in the string "@M@yte@st1@" must fail too because even there are not 3 pairs of chars there are 4 repetitions of a char (the second expression).As an example a string that i want to pass is : M@Ytteest --> not over 3 times a pair, not over 4 times a repetition of a char. Thanks for the help by the way

Comment: Try `^(?!.*(.)(?:.*?\1){3})(?!(?:.*(.)\2){3}).*`, see https://regex101.com/r/wtmBQE/2

Answer (score 0):

if you mean by 'combine' is AND

```
^(?!(\S)\1)(?!(\S)(?:\S*?\2){4})\S+
```

if you mean by 'combine' is OR

```
^(?!(\S)\1|(\S)(?:\S*?\2){4})\S+
```